# Swift 3.0 touchesBegan for game

Tags: ios, swift

I am a beginner of Swift coding and I have been developing my first game by using Swift 3.0 with SpriteKit and the latest version of Xcode.

In this game I want to make my main character move to the left when a user taps on the screen and if the user taps the screen again the character moves to the right etc. But the character is NOT affected by gravity.

For making this I've tried to create an action and then call it within the `touchesBegan` method. But it doesn't work. If I call the action within the `didMove` methods of the scene, it works by itself and without any user interaction.

How can I make this action for my character works *just* when a user taps on the screen?

I tried to paste the action within the `touchesBegan` method but an error compiler came out.

If you need any screenshot please let me know and I will provide it to you.

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to define two buttons. One to the left of the middle and one to the right of the middle. If I understand correctly, you want it to move right when tapping on the right side. What you must do is change the position of the player/image you have a notch to the right, when tapping right button and move the position a notch to the left when tapping the left side.